# How to Get URL with .html ending (with rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With rails I get the urls like

```
http://mywebsite/photos/1
```

but I ned to have the same with .html extension.

```
http://mywebsite/photos/1.html
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path generator can take a format option

```rb
link_to 'link text', photo_path(@photo, format: :html)
```